# Most efficient way of comparing arrays with hashes inside them based on a unique hash key in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, mongoid

I got two hashes hash_a and hash_b which are actually arrays but have hash inside them. Those hash have unique key.

```
hash_a = [
{:unique_key => 1, :data => 'data for A1'},
{:unique_key => 2, :data => 'data for A2'},
{:unique_key => 3, :data => 'data for A3'}
]

hash_b = [
{:unique_key => 1, :data => 'data for B1'},
{:unique_key => 2, :data => 'data for B2'},
{:unique_key => 4, :data => 'data for B4'},
{:unique_key => 5, :data => 'data for B5'}
]
```

Now I want to find out difference between hash_a and hash_b, such that I get the hash_c as array of new hashes present in hash_b.
I basically want `hash_b - hash_a`

So I want this output for hash_c, hash_c should be this:

```
[
{:unique_key => 1, :data => 'data for A1'},
{:unique_key => 2, :data => 'data for A2'},
{:unique_key => 3, :data => 'data for A3'},
{:unique_key => 4, :data => 'data for B4'},
{:unique_key => 5, :data => 'data for B5'}
]
```

I have tried something like this:

```
hash_c = hash_a
hash_b.each do |inner_bhash|
    found = 0

    hash_a.each do |inner_ahash|
        if(inner_ahash[:unique_key] == inner_bhash[:unique_key])
            found = 1
            break
        end
    end

    if(found==0)
        hash_c.push(inner_bhash)
    end
end
```

This is doing the trick, but I want a better way. Like hashmap or something, I don't know what.

---

In addition, I may want to see only the new entries, i.e.

```
[
  {:unique_key => 4, :data => 'data for B4'},
  {:unique_key => 5, :data => 'data for B5'}
]
```

I can do that in my code by replacing

```
hash_c = hash_a
```

with

```
hash_c = []
```

but how could I adapt this requirement in the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Hash`es you can use `merge` to do what you want - so going through making each `Array` into a `Hash` you can do the following:

```
hash_b.group_by { |e| e[:unique_key] }.
   merge(hash_a.group_by { |e| e[:unique_key] }).values.flatten
# => [{:unique_key=>1, :data=>"data for A1"}, 
#     {:unique_key=>2, :data=>"data for A2"}, 
#     {:unique_key=>4, :data=>"data for B4"}, 
#     {:unique_key=>5, :data=>"data for B5"}, 
#     {:unique_key=>3, :data=>"data for A3"}]
```

---

If you want to have just the entries of `hash_b` (which do not have a key in `hash_a`), given you already have the solution above - you can simply *subtract* `hash_a` from the result:

```
hash_b.group_by { |e| e[:unique_key] }.
  merge(hash_a.group_by { |e| e[:unique_key] }).values.flatten - hash_a
# => [{:unique_key=>4, :data=>"data for B4"}, 
#     {:unique_key=>5, :data=>"data for B5"}]
```

Another, more straight forward way is to filter out all elements of `hash_b` who have an entry in `hash_a`:

```
hash_b.select { |x| hash_a.none? { |y| x[:unique_key] == y[:unique_key] } }
# => [{:unique_key=>4, :data=>"data for B4"}, 
#     {:unique_key=>5, :data=>"data for B5"}]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, can you see my updated question, I am sorry for updating question but I also want to know how can get only the new values of hash_b ?

Comment: you all the values in hash_b which do not have entries with the same key on hash_a?

Comment: yeah, exactly that, so that is 4 and 5.

Comment: The straight forward way is even better, thanks a lot for adding that too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form of [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) that takes a block.

```
 (hash_a + hash_b).uniq { |h| h[:unique_key] }
  #=> [{:unique_key=>1, :data=>"data for A1"}, {:unique_key=>2, :data=>"data for A2"},
  #    {:unique_key=>3, :data=>"data for A3"}, {:unique_key=>4, :data=>"data for B4"},
  #    {:unique_key=>5, :data=>"data for B5"}]
```

To quote the doc, "self is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept."